# Use Java to build an index of files in Windows 10

Tags: java, linux, powershell

I am writing a desktop application in Java to quickly find files. I have used the exec command in Java to run powershell to do this, as Java's os.walk method seems to be much slower. Right now it takes about 5 minutes to generate a text file that lists the contents of all files on my computer (a total of around 440,000 files).

This is fine, but the problem I have is that I have no way of updating this list of files. So if I change a few files in my file system and want to update my file list, I can't do so quickly (i.e. incrementally). Instead, I have to generate the file list all over from scratch.

I know you can use git-bash to create a locate database (using updatedb). Now this is an awesome solution, but the application I'm trying to create may be used by people who don't have that installed. So I'd like to do it using default apps provided with Windows (i.e. powershell, or natively in Java). I am trying to make this app easy to use, so I don't want the user to have to install a bunch of other dependencies.

Comment: can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: The Files.walk… methods are somewhat slow because they retrieve file attributes.  But if you just want to list file names, a recursive method that does it with DirectoryStreams is quite fast, even for hundreds of thousands of files.  As for monitoring changes, you probably want to register each directory in the tree with a [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#newWatchService%28%29).

Comment: Very helpful, VGR. I will give this a try and let you know how well it worked. Lazycoder_007, I will then post my code to show my results.

Comment: So if I use DirectoryStreams to recursively list my files in the tree into some kind of database, then how do I store and update this database when a WatchService key tells me something's been changed? I don't want to have to rewrite the whole database every time a WatchKey is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows how to use Java and avoid Powershell altogether. It builds an array in memory and writes it to a text file (467,000 files listed) all in under 30 seconds!

Run the following code in Main or wherever you want. It calls the createFileList method.

```
List<Path> pathsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Path rootPath_obj;
rootPath_obj = Paths.get(this.configMap.get("root_path"));
createFileList(rootPath_obj);
```

Here's the tree stream traversal code:

```
public void createFileList(Path path_in) throws IOException, AccessDeniedException {

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> mystream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path_in)) {

        for (Path entry : mystream) {
            if (Files.isDirectory(entry)) {
                createFileList(entry);
            }
            pathsArrayList.add(entry);
        }
    }
    catch (AccessDeniedException ex) {
        // Do nothing, just move on to the next file
    }
}
```

Now write the file to save for later. This is the listing of all files within the root path tree.

```
    System.out.println("Writing database...");
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(this.configMap.get("db_path"))) {
        for(Path pth: pathsArrayList){
            writer.write(pth.toString() + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("...database written.");
```